# Way to implement handling duration of a keypress

Tags: c#, input, xna, keypress

I'm using XNA (C#) to develop a 2D platformer.
I was wondering for the best way to handle holding down a specific button. For example the more you hold down the larger the laser beam gets.

So far, since I'm already using the input mechanism that holds the 2 last states of the Keyboard, I can make an extra check each update cycle to increase the duration. But, this approach is rather limited since it only handles a specific button (fire button i.e.) and it should do the trick, but i was wondering if maybe there's a more general solution to the problem.

Comment: As far as I can tell from reading the XNA KeyboardState documentation, there's no such limitation on the KeyboardState class as the one you describe.   Judging from the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203903%28v=xnagamestudio.10%29.aspx), you should be able to use it to get the current state of every key, no matter how many are pressed down and no matter how long they've been pressed down for.   Perhaps there's an issue with your input code?

Comment: Thanks for checking it up, i confirmed your findings myself.
And I'm also aware of the input mechanics, it's just i was fishing for a more of a design/architecture solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float ElapsedSecondsPerFrame = (float) gametime.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

KeyFirePressedTime = Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(FireKey) 
                         ? (KeyFirePressedTime + ElapsedSecondsPerFrame ) 
                         : 0;
```

Generic method

```
Dictionary<int, float> PressedKeysTime = new ...


void Update(float Elapsed)
{
      List<int> OldPressedKeys = PressedKeysTime.Keys.ToList();
      foreach (int key in Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys.Cast<int>())
      {
           if (!PressedKeysTime.ContainsKey(key)) 
           {
                PressedKeysTime[key] = 0;
           } else {
               OldPressedKeys.Remove(key);
               PressedKeysTime[key] += Elapsed;
           }
      }
      foreach (int keynotpressed in OldPressedKeys) 
          PressedKeysTime.Remove(keynotpressed);

}
```

Comment: there is no other different approachs to handling the duration of a keypress, you have to accumulate time when the key fire is pressed... I can't understand where is the matter...

Comment: I was thinking more in the line of a more robust system for handling the duration management. Maybe some helper class with a more generic approach , 3rd party library as a reference ...

Comment: One line of code is robust... :), I would look for a library to do something more hard... I think there is a generic way to do it, using getpressedkeys method... but is not worth confronted with a single line of code

Answer (score 0):

To Detect a single keypress...

```
lastKeyboardState = CurrentKeyState;
CurrentKeyState = Keyboard.GetState();

if ((CurrentKeyState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Enter)) && (lastKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
        {
            //Enter was pressed
        }
```

To detect a key being held down...

```
lastKeyboardState = CurrentKeyState;
CurrentKeyState = Keyboard.GetState();
if (CurrentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter)
        {
            //Enter was pressed (You could do BeamSize++ here
        }
```

That seems the best way to do it. Is that the method you are already using?

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple pseudo-code example:

```
// to cancel immediately
if key is pressed this frame, but was released last frame
   begin effect

else if key is pressed this frame, and also was last frame
   increase magnitude of effect

else if key is released this frame and effect is active
   end effect


// or to gradually decrease
if key is pressed this frame, and effect is inactive
   begin effect

else if key is pressed this frame, and effect is active
   increase magnitude of effect

else if key is released this frame and effect is active
   decrease magnitude of effect
   if magnitude decreased enough, end effect
```

To specifically measure the duration as you say would be something like this:

```
public void Update(GameTime pGameTime)
{
   private TimeSpan mKeyDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);

   ...

   if key is pressed this frame
      mKeyDuration += pGameTime.ElapsedGameTime;

   else if key was pressed last frame
      mKeyDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);

   ...
}
```

Comment: Yes , that's kind of a way I'm currently implementing.
But I'm afraid the problem itself is in the counting the duration of the keypress. In the scenario you described I implement it in the "increase magnitde" step.
I was thinking if there's maybe some out-of-the-box functionality.